# Python print statement outputs for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am beginner in Elastic Beanstalk. I deployed a flask application which works fine. However, I cannot see the outputs of print statement that exists in python script. I can observe them in Heroku by using command "heroku logs --tail".

Briefly, I want to learn "heroku logs --tail" equivalent for Elastic Beanstalk if any. I tried some logging options but still cannot find outputs in any log files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

One way is to use logging within the app using the 'logging' package. A few quick hints:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='record.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format=f'%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s')
```

Should be called after your app is declared.
You may also use:

```
current_app.logger.info("Your message here")
```

to log specific events in the file.

Comment: Where will be the location of this log file?

Comment: This should be your python current working directory. You may check it with os.getcwd() when you run the app.